# Combining routes of frontend and backend

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have a React front-end and Flask API as back-end.
I wish to have both front-end and back-end routes accessible at same address. E.g frontend at `myapp.web.com` and backend at `myapp.web.com/api`.
It will have different deployments for them. I want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same domain that can point to multiple services based on the path.
Normally this can help you to resolve the `CORS` issue.

API

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  name: backend-ingress
  namespace: backend-api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.web.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service-name
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.web.com
    secretName: my-secret-tls
```

Frontend ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: frontend-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.web.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service-name
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.web.com
    secretName: my-secret-tls
```

so in this case, all the requests that start with `/api` will route to the backend app and rest of the requests will route to frontend.